# Instantiating UIViewController in a test

Tags: ios, swift, testing

I'm working in Swift 2, and would like to test functions within my view controller. I've made a dependency injection-like service which looks like this:

```
extension UIViewController: {
    func getDbService() -> IDbService {
        let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        return DbService(context: context)
    }
}
```

With this, I can set AppDelegate's context as a mocked one for test purposes. However, the problem arises when I try to instantiate a view controller. Here's the code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var token: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dbService = getDbService() 
        self.token = dbService.getToken() 
        //....do stuff with token 
    }
}
```

I instantiate the test like so:

```
class LoginViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    func testTokenExists() {
        let mockContext = MockContextUtils.getMockContext()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.managedObjectContext = mockContext
        let sut = LoginViewController()
        let _ = sut.view // Apparently this renders the view; I set a breakpoint, viewDidLoad is called
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.token) // FAILS, BECAUSE APPDELEGATE CALLS APP DATABASE, AND NOT MOCK.
    }
}
```

The reason this simple test fails is because LoginViewController has no idea what app delegate is. Is there a way to introduce that in the initialization phase?

Comment: Your extension doesn't refer to the app delegate's `dbService` property - it returns a new `DBService` using the app delegates `managedObjectContext`

Comment: I realized my error while trying to simplify the model. I've made changes: setting appDelegate.managedObjectContext = mockContext, and the same error occurs.

Comment: Is managedObjectContext a simple property?  Typically it is a computed property that is used to instantiate the managedObjectContext lazily.

Comment: Yes it is. Just checked managedObjectContext, it's untouched from CoreData import. Should anything be changed?

Comment: Where do you set `managedObjectContext` normally? Ie when not testing

Comment: When not testing, it's a class variable of AppDelegate, and automatically set. I don't set it; it's already populated.

Comment: Something has to set it. My guess is that something is setting it after you have set it to the mock. If you used the standard Swift CoreData template in Xcode it is set by the function `managedObjectContext` in the AppDelegate

Comment: I think it's done internally; I did a system search, and it doesn't appear to be set in my code. What would the ramifications be if I removed the lazy marker?

Comment: It has to be set somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96763/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ivan-peng).

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that initializing the view controller with its default controller does not grab the app delegate which we set up in the test. Instead, I've initialized the view controller through the storyboard via so:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let sut = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? LoginViewController
XCTAssertNotNil(sut)
XCTAssertNotNil(sut.view)
XCTAssertNotNil(sut.token)
```

which solves the problem.